# piechart using devexpress, pass values from variables

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress for WinForms (the free one) and I'm using a 3D pie chart.
I already have a chart using the Windows version and all I do is pass four variables as the values the chart needs in the series.
Here's the code I use currently.

```
double[] yValues = { bottom, bmid, tmid, top};
string[] xNames = { "Greater than 200", "Between 200-100", "Between 100-50",                "Below 50" };

chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
```

Now, I've made a DevExpress chart and tried to use:

```
   Devchart1.series[0].points
```

but `points.databind` does not exist.
Does anyone know how I bind the data like I have using WinForms?

**UPDATE**
Here's some more things I tried (commented out).

```
        double[] yValues = { bottom, bmid, tmid, top};
        string[] xNames = { "Greater than 200", "Between 200-100", "Between 100-50", "Below 50" };

        chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);

        DataTable chartTable = new DataTable("Table1");

        // Add two columns to the table.
        chartTable.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
        chartTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Below 50", top);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Between 50-100", tmid);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Between 100-200", bmid);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Greater than 200", top);

        Series series1 = new Series("Series1", ViewType.Pie3D);

        chartControl2.Series.Add(series1);

        series1.DataSource = chartTable;
        series1.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;
        series1.ArgumentDataMember = "names";
        series1.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
        series1.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });
        //((Pie3DSeriesView)series1.View). = true;
        //((pie)chartControl2.Diagram).AxisY.Visible = false;
        chartControl2.Legend.Visible = false;

        // Dock the chart into its parent and add it to the current form.
        chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

::UPDATE2::
heres what happens with this code with values 101, 22, 20 and 15.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevExpress [Series](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/DevExpressXtraChartsSeriesMembersTopicAll) has `DataSource` property for binding.

Check this [article](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/DevExpressXtraChartsSeries_DataSourcetopic). Hope it helps

**UPDATE:**
 I use your code and it seems to work fine

```
        DataTable chartTable = new DataTable("Table1");

        // Add two columns to the table.
        chartTable.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
        chartTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Below 50", 10);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Between 50-100", 10);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Between 100-200", 10);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Greater than 200", 10);

        Series series1 = new Series("Series1", ViewType.Pie3D);

        //chartControl1.Series.Clear();
        chartControl2.Series.Add(series1);

        series1.DataSource = chartTable;
        series1.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;
        series1.ArgumentDataMember = "names";
        series1.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
        series1.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });
        //((Pie3DSeriesView)series1.View). = true;
        //((pie)chartControl2.Diagram).AxisY.Visible = false;
        chartControl2.Legend.Visible = false;
```

[image]

Comment: updated my code, so far ive tried a few things but iether, errors at run time complaining about invalid arguments, or no display being shown

Comment: Try to create `DataTable` like in example, and bind it

Comment: ok ive run the program without errors but when i hit the button the 3d piechart decideds to show (what i think to be) default values, ive gone into the properties and removed all series to make sure there no conflict.
any ideas? ill update you with the code i have

Comment: try changing the values of top bottom etc

Comment: ok i deleted the chart i created using the wizard, and created a brand new one, i selected 3d pie chart and selected finish so ive made 0 changes to its properties.......and still it shows up some imaginary numbers.... as a default

Comment: ok top = 101, tmid = 22, bmid = 20 and bottom = 13
Ive also updated my post with  pic of the chart

Comment: it clearly does not show 101 22 20 and 13 its more to me like 101 101 22 20

Comment: you have a typo in your code you add top in "Greater than 200" instead of bottom

Comment: omg, why is it always something so stupid xD.  many thanks for the help and baring with me!